# Length (column) greater than but spaces after the characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query to show all records where column is greater than 4 characters, however, the data contains spaces after the characters for example '1234     ' .

How could I modify the below query to ignore the spaces after the characters? Querying an Oracle database.

Many thanks.

```
select * 
from tablename
where length(field1) > 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rtrim` function to remove the trailing spaces.

```
select * 
from tablename 
where length(rtrim(field1)) > 4
```

Perhaps you want to check `ltrim`, `trim` functions, too.